# Receiving data in my app from hardware device using bluetooth connection in wrong view

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have hardware device which sends me some data using Bluetooth connection every second. And when I received data sometimes I have 2 message and sometimes 1. Can someone explain to me why?

> Log

```
I/BluetoothChatService: 3
I/BluetoothChatService: 1
I/BluetoothChatService: 3
I/BluetoothChatService: 1
I/BluetoothChatService: 31
I/BluetoothChatService: 31
I/BluetoothChatService: 31
I/BluetoothChatService: 31
```

> Read

```
    public  void run () {
        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                numBytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, numBytes);
                Log.i(TAG, readMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is he actual question?

Comment: @mbuechmann as u can see In my log message I received 32 and sometimes 3 and than 2.

Comment: Please do not post output as images. Post the actual text with an indentation of 4 spaces.

Comment: I/ displayed from your Log.i message and E/ displayed from e.printStackTrace() from some reason, in generally I is from info and E from error log

Comment: What do the numbers in the output mean?

Comment: @mbuechmann temperature from sensor

Comment: What lets you think that you sometimes get multiple messages? Where in your code is that? Could you place a comment at that line?